# Generalization of the multinomial theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For $\{ε_i\}\in l^1(\mathbb Z)$ such that $ε_i>0$ for all $i\in\mathbb Z$, is it true that$$\left(\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}ε_k\right)^{2d}=\sum_{k_1,\cdots,k_{2d}\in\mathbb Z}\prod_{i=1}^{2d}ε_{k_i}?$$
If it is true, can you give me a reference? If it is not true, can you give me what is the first term equal to of the equality above? Or just an estimate?

Thank you.

Comment: $(\varepsilon_i) \subset l^1(\mathbb{Z})$

Comment: Can you clarify what $l^1(\mathbb{Z})$ is?

Comment: $\sum_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}\varepsilon_i <\infty$